# Plotting multiple line graph Pandas in grouped data(Python)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I have this data frame called manager:

```
                    
Manager Month_name  Sales
Chris   Apr         64058.38
        Feb         70282.44
        Jan         62622.83
        Jun         106073.62
        Mar         65994.29
        May         79253.14 

Erin    Apr         189208.29
        Feb         69708.83
        Jan         66033.43
        Jun         123225.09
        Mar         59137.04
        May         84858.81

Sam     Apr         64087.87
        Feb         31754.39
        Jan         73062.34
        Jun         53236.50
        Mar         77874.78
        May         57089.24

William Apr         72477.41
        Feb         154355.81
        Jan         73048.32
        Jun         72833.59
        Mar         68690.56
        May         85370.88
```

and I would want my graph to look like this
[image: graph]

Of course, each manager has his line in the graph, I just drew two. Can somebody please help me out with suggestions how to make it?

Answer (score 0):

```
m = ['Apr', 'Feb', 'Jan', 'Jun', 'Mar', 'May']

chris = manager.loc['Chris']
erin = manager.loc['Erin']
sam = manager.loc['Sam']
william = manager.loc['William']

plt.plot(m, chris, label = "Chris", marker = 'o', markerfacecolor = "blue" )
plt.plot(m, erin, label = "Erin", marker = 'o', markerfacecolor = "orange" )
plt.plot(m, sam, label = "Sam", marker = 'o', markerfacecolor = "green")
plt.plot(m, william, label = "William", marker = 'o', markerfacecolor ="red" )

plt.xlabel("Months")
plt.ylabel("Sales")
plt.title("Managers success in Sales")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And here is the image
[image]